# Let $x$ be an element of the group $G$. Prove that $x^2 = 1$ if and only if $|x|$ is either $1$ or $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Let $x$ be an element of the group $G$. Prove that $x^2 = 1$ *iff* $|x|$ is either $1$ or $2$

Now I know that $G$ is implicitly a group under multiplication, therefore $G = (A, \ \cdot \ )$, for some underlying set $A$.

The problem I'm facing is that $A$ could be any set. So now if we take $A = \mathbb{R}$, then $x^2 = 1 \implies |x| = 1$, but it certainly does not imply that $|x| = 2$. So how is this problem even well defined?

This problem is taken from *Chapter 1: Group Theory - Exercise 16 in 'Abstarct Algebra' by Dummit and Foote*

Is there a mistake in this problem? If not how would one proceed to prove that $x^2 = 1$ *iff* $|x|$ is either $1$ or $2$, despite the counterexample I gave above?

Comment: $|x|$ means the order of $x$.  It has nothing to do with absolute value.  It is the smallest number $n$ such that $x^n$ is the identity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of this problem, $|x|$ presumably means the order of $x$ as an element of $G$, not the absolute value of $x$.  That is, $|x|$ is the least positive integer $n$ such that $x^n=1$ (where $x^n$ means $x$ multiplied with itself $n$ times using the group operation of $G$, and $1$ means the identity element of $G$).

Answer (score 2):

You need not attempt to deduce properties of this specific group or set. This is true because of the group properties in general, not of $G = (A, \cdot )$. You may also want to read your textbook further, by conventional context in group theory, $|a|$ is by definition the order, which is the lowest positive integer such that $a^n = 1 \implies |a| = n$. If $|a| = 1$, then $a^1, a^2, a^3, ....$ is always going to be $1$ since any positive integer divides $1$. If $|a| = 2$, you immediately have $a^2 = 1$

Comment: I hope you meant: any positive integer is divided by $1$.